# How to display a message while loading data from graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

I am developing a facebook application. When the user calls my App for the first time, I need to retrieve a big amount of data from his profile through the graph API. While doing this the canvas page of my application remains blank. What I want to do is while waiting the data to be fetched, show to the user a message ex "Please wait, loading..." instead of a blank page. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX to make the request and then once you have the data use Javascript to insert it into the HTML.

These two tutorials may help:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/display-loading-gif-image-while-loading.html

http://codingrecipes.com/ajax-beginner-ajax-tutorial-display-a-progress-bar-or-a-loading-message

Ultimately, you should probably due some reading on Javascript and AJAX before you ask a question like this on StackOverflow. We can't write code for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! I did not ask anyone to provide me code. The tutorial are more than enough.

Comment: No problem, glad I could be helpful.

Comment: I wasn't going to say anything... :)